# ClosedXML Rich Text

Tags: c#, richtext, closedxml

Prior to Version 0.96.0, I was able to add rich text using ClosedXML as follows:

```
ws.Cell("M3").Value = "";
ws.Cell("M3").RichText.AddText("⌧ ").Bold = false;
ws.Cell("M3").RichText.AddText("Total Joint").Bold = true;
```

The result is a non-bold checked box, followed by a bold label "Total Joint".  Rich Text has now been updated to use the `CreateRichText` method of the cell, but the method does not appear to take overloads.  I can do the following:

```
ws.Cell("M3").CreateRichText();
ws.Cell("M3").Value = @"⌧ Total Joint";
```

But I can't figure out how to bold and unbold.

I tried using \b and \b0, but that just literally printed \b and \b0.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  The upgrade notes did not refer me to any documentation I was able to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
var richtText = ws.Cell("M3").CreateRichText();
richText.AddText("⌧ ")
var richString = richText.AddText("Total Joint");
richString.Bold = true;
```